# Music player supporting resumption after close

Tags: linux, music, ubuntu, mp3

I'm looking for a music player for Ubuntu Linux that supports resuming the song, position in that song, and the playlist in which the song was located once I open it again (essentially saving state on close and resuming on reopen). It also must:

- Support playlists or something like it
- Be able to open an m3u playlist
- Be able to open a directory as a playlist or create a playlist from the directory

I've already tried the following:

- VLC Media Player - supported everything except playlist and song resume
- Rhythmbox - supported everything except playlist and song position resume

What media player for Ubuntu is capable of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org/) is my preferred music player.
It fits all your needs and many more.

- Resume playback (check)
- Support playlists (check)
- Be able to open an m3u playlist (check)
- Be able to open a directory as a playlist or create a playlist from the directory (check)

It's in the Ubuntu repositories. Install via Software Center or Commandline

```
sudo apt-get install clementine
```

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions! Both Clementine and Audacious fulfilled all of my needs, but your answer was posted 4 minutes before @karel's, so I'll be marking it as correct.

Comment: Clementine is "inspired by [amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/)", that I highly recommend, too. The distinction between Clementine and Amarok is probably a matter of taste, but they are both excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Audacious supports resuming playback in the song, position in that song, and the playlist in which the song was located once you open it again and press the green play icon in the toolbar to resume playing the song from the position where it was stopped.

Other features supported in Audacious are:

- Create playlists by dragging the songs from the Files app into the playlist.
- A playlist can include songs that have different audio coding formats (e.g. .mp3, .m4a) in the same playlist.
- Export a playlist as a file with an .m3u extension.
- Play an .m3u playlist.
- Album art is shown when a song is played. Album art of a song and its song information is shown when you hover the mouse over a song in the Audacious window.

Audacious can be installed in all supported versions of Ubuntu with the command:

```
sudo apt install audacious
```

I also recommend that you don't uninstall the default Rhythmbox music player, so that you can continue to use Rhythmbox for managing your music library.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions! Both Clementine and Audacious fulfilled all of my needs, but @RoVo's answer was posted 4 minutes before yours, so I'll be marking RoVo's as correct.

Comment: In addition, Audacious didn't remember well between boots. In my test, I played a song from an imported playlist, paused, then rebooted and tried to resume playback. Unfortunately, Audacious remembered every single playlist *except* the one I was playing, while Clementine rembered it just fine, better fulfilling my requirements. <br><br> But thanks for your answer! You got my upvote!